# update second level dict array object using a reference dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of dicts and within each one if have another array of dicts. my original dict like this

```
[{'substepheading': 'Heading 1',
  'substepnumber': '1',
  'substepparams': [{'name': 'upload file', 'paramselected': 'no'}]},
 {'substepheading': 'Heading 2',
  'substepnumber': '2',
  'substepparams': [{'name': 'clean data', 'paramselected': 'no'}]}]
```

I have another dict which contains the updates to specified step numbers and params like this

```
[{'substepnumber': 2, 'substepparams': [{'name': 'clean room'}]}]
```

I tried this but the subarray is not getting updated properly

```
    for substep in substepdetails:
        for modifiedsubstep in substepdetailstoupdate:
            if((modifiedsubstep['substepnumber']) == int(substep['substepnumber'])):
                substep.update(modifiedsubstep)
```

The second level array of dicts is getting overridden like this

```
[{'substepheading': 'choose file',
  'substepnumber': '1',
  'substepparams': [{'name': 'upload file', 'paramselected': 'no'}]},
 {'substepheading': 'prepare the data',
  'substepnumber': '2',
  'substepparams': [{'name': 'clean room'}]}]
```

I know I can add one more internal loop for this particular case but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to update dicts in situations like this, especially if there can be multiple sub levels like this

EDIT: Desired output is like this

```
[{'substepheading': 'choose file',
      'substepnumber': '1',
      'substepparams': [{'name': 'upload file', 'paramselected': 'no'}]},
     {'substepheading': 'prepare the data',
      'substepnumber': '2',
      'substepparams': [{'name': 'clean room', 'paramselected': 'no'}]}]
```

Comment: Create a pandas dataframe and update the dataframe. Later convert the dataframe to json

Comment: Can you check your example? Where is the word "service" coming from? Same for "select template".

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko sorry for that. made the edits

Comment: Hold on, could you also post the desired output?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko added the desired output

Comment: @SujayDSa thanks, made an edit to the answer. I made a guess about your desired behavior in case some 'substepparams' list has more than one element since it is not clear from your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need is two loops over your data and one loop over your updates (no nested loops). The idea is to create a `dict` or `records` that maps `substepnumber` to `substepparams`. (Note that this assumes no repetition of `substepparams`. This case can be handled with a bit extra work.)

For each update, you can access the respective `substepnumber` in amortized O(1) time and update each dict in the associated `substepparams` list.

Because `records` and `data` reference the same dicts, your original data will be automatically updated.

```
data = [
    {
        "substepheading": "Heading 1",
        "substepnumber": "1",
        "substepparams": [{"name": "upload file", "paramselected": "no"}],
    },
    {
        "substepheading": "Heading 2",
        "substepnumber": "2",
        "substepparams": [{"name": "clean data", "paramselected": "no"}],
    },
]

# converted substepnumber to str in order to match the data format.
updates = [{"substepnumber": "2", "substepparams": [{"name": "clean room"}]}]

records = {d["substepnumber"]: d["substepparams"] for d in data}
for num, params in ((d["substepnumber"], d["substepparams"]) for d in updates):
    [dct.update(upd) for dct in records[num] for upd in params]


[
    {
        "substepheading": "Heading 1",
        "substepnumber": "1",
        "substepparams": [{"name": "upload file", "paramselected": "no"}],
    },
    {
        "substepheading": "Heading 2",
        "substepnumber": "2",
        "substepparams": [{"name": "clean room", "paramselected": "no"}],
    },
]
```

Comment: Note that this if a list of 'substepparams' has more than one element, each element will be updated. Similarly, if a list of 'substepparams' in an update has multiple dicts, each dict will be used to make an update.

Comment: beautiful! thanks! works well with multiple dicts in the list.